# Android webDriver selenium tests fail to run on Emulators but working superb on Real Devices

Tags: selenium, android-emulator, webdriver

Getting different sort of errors on test execution,

1) `NosuchelementFound`

2) `Could not locate the element`

3) `NullPointerException, etc.,`

Is there any fix or still an issue?